# PHP will not execute linux bash

Tags: php, html, bash, virtual-machine

I am trying to execute an html function that will use a php file to run a linux bash script and shutdown a group of headless VMs. The bash script will successfully run on its own, but the php file is not executing the script. I made sure to add the correct line to sudoers.

```
#!/bin/bash
VM_NAME='wintgt1'
VBoxManage controlvm $VM_NAME poweroff

VM_NAME='wintgt2'
VBoxManage controlvm $VM_NAME poweroff

VM_NAME='wintgt3'
VBoxManage controlvm $VM_NAME poweroff
```

PHP

```
<?php
shell_exec("sudo /etc/init.d/portstop.sh");
header("Location: http://192.168.1.21/mod/page/view.php?id=133&forceview$");
?>
```

I have other scripts with the same sudoers entries and php files in the same location as this one. However, this particular php file is not executing the script.
Thanks

Comment: I guess `VBoxManage` requires a sudo user? Which `www-data` user is not.

Comment: Just looking at your other question, same applies..

Comment: I was able to fix the issue that i had in my previous question. I used the same method for this one, but its not working.

Comment: Can you show the sudoers line

Comment: www-data ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD: /etc/init.d/portstop.sh

Comment: Not sure id have to check, but I think you should add VBoxManage to sudoers instead, then put sudo in front of all the cmds not in front of the bash script call.

Comment: also the way you're calling it in php, have you added execute bit on portstop.sh?

Comment: changed that thanks. The script still works, but no luck on the call.

Comment: explain execute bit? do you mean chmod +x ?

Comment: Yeah, instead of using shell_exec use exec then you can debug it abit more: https://3v4l.org/pkU5e also enable error reporting and check the error logs. remove the header till you get it working, thats goto be annoying ;p

Comment: thank you ill pull the error

Comment: sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified

Comment: without sudo in the php exec line it tells me that it cant find the appropriate registered VMs

Comment: that error means its prompting for password, seems like sudoers is not right

Comment: heres what i added 
www-data ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/VBoxManage
www-data ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/lib/virtualbox/VBoxManage

Comment: I'm not familiar with VBoxManage, I use LXD.. I also suspect you have $PATH issue as well.

Comment: In the init script, you would want to specify the full path to VboxManage, and make sure you provide any other environment setting that program requires. Don't forget, that script will not be executing in your shell environment.

Comment: ive tried to paths in the script below and still no success                          
   #!/bin/bash
   /usr/lib/virtualbox/VBoxManage controlvm wintgt1 poweroff
   /usr/bin/VBoxManage controlvm wintgt2 poweroff
   /usr/bin/VBoxManage controlvm wintgt3 poweroff

Comment: should i move the script to /usr/local/bin ? if so would i need to include any file paths in the .sh

Comment: echo $PATH
/home/ddlpadmin/bin:/home/ddlpadmin/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin